# TCPListener multithreading communication with multiple clients

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, tcpclient

My application is designed to listen for incoming messages from clients over TCP. What I'm using is TCPListner and "BeginAcceptTcpClient" method. On connection established what I'm doing is creating a new thread for each connection using:
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HandleClientCommNew), client);

My question here is, what happens to the thread when the Callback function finishes its work. If the answer is it gets terminated on it's own, my problem is that it isn't and I'm getting a huge number of threads hanging in my process, otherwise what is the best practice of terminated the thread.

On a side note, the clients in question handles connections and disconnections on their own meaning I have to control over them.

**EDIT**

```
public void Init() 
{
     this.tcpListener = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 1000);
     this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
}

private void ListenForClients()
{
     this.tcpListener.Start();
     StartAccept();
}

public void StartAccept()
{
     this.tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(DoAcceptTcpClientCallback), tcpListener);

}

public void DoAcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
     StartAccept();
     TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
     TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HandleClientCommNew), client);
}

private static void HandleClientCommNew(object stateInfo)
{
     TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)stateInfo;
     AsyncCallback callback = null;
     callback = ar =>
     {
          bytesRead = clientStream.EndRead(ar);
          clientStream.BeginRead(message, 0, 4500, callback, null);
     }

     clientStream.BeginRead(message, 0, 4500, callback, null);
}
```

Comment: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem doesn't create dedicated thread per se. How do you know you have many "threads hanging" in your process? Where do you see this?

Comment: Widnows 7 Resource Monitor

Comment: Those are just ThreadPool threads. A typical .net process will end up with many Managed (and O/S level) threads which belong to a threadpool. You don't need to worry about terminating them.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't implement the async pattern right. If you show your code we at least have a chance of finding the issue.

Comment: The code looks fine. You don't need to queue HandleClientCommNew because thanks to async IO it returns very quickly (after setting up the first IO). Anyway, this should not cause any problems.; When you pause the debugger, where do all the threads stand? You say there is a huge number of them. Post some call stacks.

Comment: Cannot debug it actually, it's a windows service. My problem is, knowing beforehand the number of expected client connecting to my server, the application ends up holding double or maybe more the count of threads. My guess is the client disconnecting and connecting, however the old thread prior to disconnection is still alive

Comment: Attach the debugger to the running process. Then you can debug normally.

Comment: No debugging, service is running on clients server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happens to the thread when the Callback function finishes its work.

You can think of threadpool threads as robots or agents waiting for tasks to be assigned to them. They just keep working on tasks assigned to them and after the task is done they wait for more tasks. You don't need to terminate them, that responsibility lies with the ThreadPool class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you queue a method into the ThreadPool, it will be picked-up by a thread from the threadpool. When the method ends, the thread will wait for another job. You should queue longrunning jobs on the ThreadPool, like waiting for receiving data. There are limited threads handling the jobs queued on the threadpool. So if you have `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads` clients, your application can't handle more clients.

---

You shouldn't use the ThreadPool for connections.

Rather use the asynchronous BeginReceive/EndReceive. Because these use the *I/O Completion Ports* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx and don't block a ThreadPool thread while waiting. When some data is read, a new job will be queued on the ThreadPool. (so it's not waiting there)

Pseudo:

```
StartListening() <-----------------------------------------------+
{                                                                |
    BeginAcceptTcpClient(... EndListening); >----+               |
}                                                |               |
                                                 |               |
EndListening() <---------------------------------+               |
{                                                                |
    TcpClient client = EndAcceptTcpClient(..);                   |
                                                                 |
    StartClientReceiving(client); >--------------------------+   |
                                                             |   |
    StartListening(); >-------------------------------------/#\--+
}                                                            |
                                                             |
StartClientReceiving(TcpClient client) <---------------------+
{                                                          \
    client.BeginReceiving(....EndClientReceiving) >---+    |
}                                                     |    |
                                                      |    |
EndClientReceiving() <--------------------------------+    |
{                                                          |
    // if no datareceived, disconnect.                     |
    // HandleData                                          |
    StartClientReceiving(); >------------------------------+
}
```

I've got an example of the socket listener/reader on my blog: http://csharp.vanlangen.biz/network-programming/async-sockets/

Comment: Quote: _There are limited threads handling the jobs queued on the threadpool. So if you have ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads * clients, your application can't handle more clients._ And the communication turns bad. (timeouts) It's not that using the `ThreadPool` is wrong, but waiting on the `ThreadPool` is not recommented.